# Unit testing that component renders correctly - invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing

I am working on a learning project to get familiar with React and Typescript. I have created a stopwatch component and I want to simply test that it renders without crashing, as I know it works fine in the browser.

The following code fails with an invalid hook call error message. "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." I am unsure what the cause of this issue might be, I was thinking I am setting my test in a wrong way.

```
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { Stopwatch } from "../../Components/Stopwatch";
import * as React from "react";
import {
  onAddClick,
  isEnabled,
  setAddButtonEnabled,
} from "../Fixtures/stopwatch";

test("renders without crashing", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Stopwatch />);
  expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

The imports for `onAddClick`, `isEnabled` and `setAddButtonEnabled` are mock props I used to pass to the Stopwatch component, as I thought initially that this might fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across the same issue, apparently, there is a bug in React related to updating state in shallow wrappers, so the fix is to replace `shallow` with `mount`.

So, in my case `const wrapper = mount(<Stopwatch/>);`